# Error during pip install: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pip

I'm having issues during the package installation of license.

I've tried

```
pip install license
pip install license --user
python -m pip install license --user
```

but whatever I do, I get the same error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

```
py --version and pip --version
```

shows Python 3.7.0 and pip 19.3.1

I've already read that everything I did already should've helped, which is not the case.

Can somebody please give me guidance on this topic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try to install the module with admin rights ? That means if you are using `Linux`, use `sudo pip install` or in `windows` open the `cmd` as administrator!

Comment: Tried opening cmd as administrator, still ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-92u2vff4\\license\\LICENSE'
Check the permissions.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/license/#files says this module is only for `Linux` and `Mac OSs` .

Comment: Holy crap, I messed up... it should be "licensening", not "license"... Issue solved! Thank you so much for pointing out my stupidity!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in case of linux environments.

`sudo chown user -R env`